# Choosing an integer at random among the indices of a given list

Tags: python, random

In Python 3.x, I need to choose an integer at random among the indices of a given list. In other words, given

```
mylist = [0, 5, 6, 8, -10]
```

I want to return a number between 0 and 4. What's the most Pythonic way to do it? I tried

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [0, 5, 6, 8, -10]
def choose_at_random(a_list):
    choice = np.random.randint(0, len(a_list))
    return choice
```

This works, but is this the Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: `random.randint` is inclusive in both ends.

Comment: @Asocia so I need to remove the `+1`, right?

Comment: I don't know about the `np.random.randint` but for builtin `random.randint` you don't need the `+1` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use something from Python's standard library (and don't need anything vectorised like `numpy`) [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) is generally the easiest method for accomplishing this.

You'd use it something like:

```py
from random import randrange
from typing import Sized

def random_index_from_sized(a_list: Sized) -> int:
    return randrange(len(a_list))

my_list = [0, 5, 6, 8, -10]

random_index_from_sized(my_list)
```

which would return an integer value in [0, 4].

[`numpy`'s `randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) is similarly defined, so could be used in the above definition as:

```
from numpy.random import randint

def random_sized_index(a_list: Sized) -> int:
    return randint(len(a_list))
```

Returning a single value from `numpy` is kind of pointless, i.e. `numpy` is designed for returning large arrays.  A quick `timeit` test says that `randrange(5)` takes ~0.3µs while `randint(5)` takes ~2µs (for a single value).  If you want, e.g., 1000 values then `[randrange(5) for _ in range(1000)]` takes ~300µs, while `randint(5, size=1000)` only takes ~20µs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
#random is in the standard library(so no need to "pip")
my_list = [0, 5, 6, 8, -10]
def choose_at_random(a_list):
    choice = (random.choice(a_list))
    return choice
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: as per Mark's comment, this doesn't explain what's going on and, worse, it does the wrong thing.  OP seems to mostly want indices into `my_list` (mostly, because they also seem to want an extra out-of-bounds index at the end as well).  you just return uniform draws from the list

Comment: @SamMason you're right that qwerty's code is doing the wrong thing. But I (OP) also shouldn't post question when my brain is in vacation mode :-D because what I really wanted is indices from `my_list`. Thanks for making me notice my mistake. The question is now fixed.

Comment: @DeltaIV was thinking of adding a comment to your question asking whether you actually meant what you were asking for, maybe I should have!  :)

Comment: @qwerty I can't remove my downvote until your answer is edited...